# How can I fire a trigger to click when using slider in android?

Tags: android, slider, onclicklistener

I am using Slider like gmail or Facbook in android this is fine. What i have done is i just created a new activity and given animation to it so it looks like slider. Now what i want is when user click any button in slider a new activity should open and perform task what i specify in it. But i am not getting how to pass click event in slider.

My code

```
public class PlayAudio extends Activity implements OnCompletionListener,
    SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

boolean alreadyShowing = false;
private int windowWidth;
private int windowHeight;
private PopupWindow fadePopup;
private Animation ta;
private RelativeLayout baseView;
LayoutInflater inflater;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.player);

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    windowWidth = display.getWidth();
    windowHeight = display.getHeight();
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);       

    findViewById(R.id.imageView1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!alreadyShowing) {
                alreadyShowing = true;
                openSlidingMenu();
            }
        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.imageView3).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!alreadyShowing) {
                alreadyShowing = true;
                openSlidingMenu();
            }
        }
    });
}

private void openSlidingMenu() {
    showFadePopup();
    int width = (int) (windowWidth * 0.8f);
    translateView((float) (width));
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    int height = LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
    // creating a popup
    final View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.option_popup_layout,
            (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.popup_element));
    final PopupWindow optionsPopup = new PopupWindow(layout, width, height,
            true);
    optionsPopup.setBackgroundDrawable(new PaintDrawable());
    optionsPopup.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 0, 0);
    optionsPopup.setOnDismissListener(new PopupWindow.OnDismissListener() {
        public void onDismiss() {
            // Removing the fade effect
            fadePopup.dismiss();
            // to clear the previous animation transition in
            cleanUp();
            // move the view out
            translateView(0);
            // to clear the latest animation transition out
            cleanUp();
            // resetting the variable
            alreadyShowing = false;
        }
    });
}

private void showFadePopup() {
    final View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fadepopup,
            (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.fadePopup));
    fadePopup = new PopupWindow(layout, windowWidth, windowHeight, false);
    fadePopup.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 0, 0);
}

private void translateView(float right) {
    ta = new TranslateAnimation(0f, right, 0f, 0f);
    ta.setDuration(100);
    ta.setFillEnabled(true);
    ta.setFillAfter(true);

    baseView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.Player_Slider);
    baseView.startAnimation(ta);
    baseView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

private void cleanUp() {
    if (null != baseView) {
        baseView.clearAnimation();
        baseView = null;
    }
    if (null != ta) {
        ta.cancel();
        ta = null;
    }
    fadePopup = null;
}
}
```

Here in click event i am calling openSlidingMenu function which open's new activity option_popup_layout (http://i.share.pho.to/fb125f6f_o.png)

Now what i want is when i click any of the image in option_popup_layout a new activity should open and i want perform some operation over there but i am not getting where i have to use click event to call new activity.

I have tried some piece of code to put click event inside creating function as well as other method too but not getting work.

Please help me to solve this. Thanks in advance.